# SFMC: Transferring email builds from existing instance to new instance

Tags: marketing-cloud, account-management, archive

Wondering if anybody has had to transfer email builds from one account to another - or perhaps found a way to bulk export emails from the content section of SFMC?

Have four years worth of emails I'd like to find a way of saving for future reference, but that aren't valuable enough to rebuild one by one. We have a small window of time between new account setup and old account cut off.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you figure out a way to do this? Am in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the SFMC API, but it's no small undertaking.   Making sure you have all of the dependencies is the secret sauce.